# How to properly initialize a model matrix in C?

Tags: c, exception, opengl

I tried to convert the code of the question I asked over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651388/why-is-the-sprite-not-rendering-in-opengl).

But when I try to run it, I run into an exception and it points to the mat4(which is an 2-d array of 4x4 floats) header of [this](https://github.com/recp/cglm)(CGLM, which is use for OpenGL math in C as GLM is C++ only library) library.

The C++ code works fine and runs perfectly but why does it crash in C.

Here is the C snippet of the code where 'CGLM' is used(this is the code that crashes):-

```
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
mat4 model =
{
    { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
    { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
};
mat4 projection;
glm_ortho(0.0f, (GLfloat)(WIDTH), (GLfloat)(HEIGHT), 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, projection);

vect2 scale = { 2.0f, 2.0f };
vect2 position = { 50.0f, 0.0f };
vec4 color = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f };
GLfloat rotation = 0.0f;

glm_translate(model, (vec3){ position[0], position[1], 0.0f });

glm_translate(model, (vec3){ 0.5f * scale[0], 0.5f * scale[1], 0.0f });
glm_rotate(model, rotation, (vec3){ 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }); // Why is this function crashing?
glm_translate(model, (vec3){ -0.5f * scale[0], -0.5f * scale[1], 0.0f });

glm_scale(model, (vec3){ scale[0] * width, scale[1] * height, 1.0f });

glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat *)projection);
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat *)model);
glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "spriteColor"), color[0], color[1], color[2], color[3]);
```

Here is the C++ snippet of the code where GLM is used:-

```
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
glm::mat4 model(1.0f);
glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<GLfloat>(WIDTH), static_cast<GLfloat>(HEIGHT), 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

glm::vec2 scale = glm::vec2(2.0f, 2.0f);
glm::vec2 position = glm::vec2(50.0f, 0.0f);
glm::vec4 color = glm::vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
GLfloat rotation = 0.0f;

model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(position, 0.0f));

model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.5f * scale.x, 0.5f * scale.y, 0.0f));
model = glm::rotate(model, rotation, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(-0.5f * scale.x, -0.5f * scale.y, 0.0f));

model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(scale * glm::vec2(width, height), 1.0f));

glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "spriteColor"), color.x, color.y, color.z, color.w);
```

Comment: So, what exception do you get, and at which point in your code?

Comment: 'Exception thrown at 0x010F59C7 in spritetest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF' is said by the compiler instanly after I run it, pointing over here:- https://github.com/recp/cglm/blob/master/include/cglm/vec4.h#L169

Comment: By the compiler? certainly not. But really, use a debugger and lock at the stack trace

Comment: @derhass I just added the link to the line which causes the exception.

Comment: Why would the `glUniform...` call end up in a cglm vector addition? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [CGLM documentation](http://cglm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mat4.html#c.glm_mat4_identity)

According to the [getting started](http://cglm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

> Aligment is Required: vec4 and mat4 requires 16 byte aligment because
>   vec4 and mat4 operations are vectorized by SIMD instructions
>   (SSE/AVX).

So you need to initialize identity matrix like:

```
mat4 model;
glm_mat4_identity(model);
....
mat4 projection;
glm_mat4_identity(projection);
glm_ortho(0.0f, (GLfloat)(WIDTH), (GLfloat)(HEIGHT), 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, projection);
```

Comment: But why is it still crashing?

Comment: Which source line ?

Comment: This one right here `model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(-0.5f * scale.x, -0.5f * scale.y, 0.0f));`

Comment: @Ruks I suppose you have a problem in the `C` code don't you ? glm_scale(model, (vec3){ scale[0] * width, scale[1] * height, 1.0f });

Comment: The same things for vectors, i.e. vec3 init = GLM_VEC3_ZERO; etc.

Comment: 'C' don't have any exceptions at all. Exceptions is a C++ feature. It it crashes - glm code, written using assembly to accelerate performance bring to undefined behavior, since data is not properly initialized (aligned). `C` is not a C++ is much closer to assembly, so try to avoid tricks like (vec3) { .... }, this is not a constructor call with std::initialized_list unlike the same in `C++`.

Comment: It is with the rotation, not the scale.

Comment: It dosn't really meter,  assembly code expecting aligned memory. `(vec3){ 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }` this is an stack object array, and compiler crossing the aliment. Assembly function expecting memory address  on array with the exact alignment. Simply don't pass the formal parameter arrays, use variables.