# OpenGL Transformations not working using GLM matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm learning the OpenGL using the learnopengl tutorials, and in the transformations chapter. I understood everything he did and the theory (maths) behind it. But while trying to practice my object isn't showing I copied his code and paste it and still nothing changed!

Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

My rendering:

```
// bind textures on corresponding texture units
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

// create transformations
glm::mat4 transform;
transform = glm::rotate(transform, glm::radians((float)glfwGetTime()), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

// get matrix's uniform location and set matrix
ourShader.use();
unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID, "transform");
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));

// render container
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

when I remove the transform from the multiplication in vertex shader everything works fine

Comment: The code is intended to provide a rotating shape. By "works fine" you mean you can see that shape but not moving, right?  This means the transform matrix when included is not correct. Try a simpler one.

Comment: You have to initialize `transform`: `glm::mat4 transform(1.0f);` - See [Why is the sprite not rendering in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651388/why-is-the-sprite-not-rendering-in-opengl/49652092#49652092).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the sprite not rendering in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651388/why-is-the-sprite-not-rendering-in-opengl)

Comment: try step-by-step stuff.Start without texture then add it .Also `glDrawElements` is a bad choice for learning purpose code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the matrix variable `glm::mat4 transform`.

The [glm API documentation](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/index.html) refers to [The OpenGL Shading Language specification 4.20](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.20.pdf).

> **5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors**
>
> If there is a single scalar parameter to a vector constructor, it is used to initialize all components of the constructed vector to that scalar’s value. **If there is a single scalar parameter to a matrix constructor, it is used to initialize all the components on the matrix’s diagonal, with the remaining components initialized to 0.0.**

This means, that an identity matrix can be initialized by the single parameter 1.0:

```
glm::mat4 transform(1.0f);
```

Comment: A life saver thanks! I already searched, what glm::mat4 default constructor do and i found that it init the mat to the identity. but thanks anyway